# Google My Business API Get location profile image or logo

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api

I am working with Google My Business API.
I need to retrieve a location profile image or location logo url.

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media#category) I need `MediaItem` with Enum `PROFILE` or `LOGO`

Problem is that I found only bulk request:

```
GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{name=accounts/*/locations/*/media/*}
```

which returns all location media (any Enum).

In this case I have to run through response to find item I am searching for and it might be necessary to run multiple requests to access next feed pages.

This approach is irrational on my opinion.

Maybe I am missing something, so is there any way to get what I want in just one request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also looking for a better way but no luck.

Comment: I agree with @unbreak, you should iterate but there is not a big deal. Depending on the language you are coding you can optimise it

Answer (score 1):

The only way is iterate through all MediaItem's